# Commands referencing Homefolder via tilde run from a script appear to operate on different folders than these commans typed directly into the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, directory, home-directory

I've recently setup a new computer and wanted to collect all commands I use to setup my system in a primitive bash script. This way I thought to have an easy start with my next setup.

However, running the command

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs ~/.emacs.d
```

from the bash script yields `Cloning into '/root/.emacs.d'`, while running it from the terminal directly actually clones into ~/.emacs.d (which I as an amateur understand to lie directly in my home folder).
Before that command there is only a simple `pacman -S` instruction in my script.
I also ran the bash script in different places (home folder and subfolders), but this has not changed the outcome.

Can someone please explain to me why the command appears to act differently from my bash script?
Is ~ when run from a script with `sudo` expanded into some sort of "Home directory of root" and if so, how may I stop this and reliably refer to the home directory of the current user that is logged in when employing the script?

As @Jetchisel pointed out, it is probably important that I run the bash script with `sudo`, which is necessary since it contains a `pacman -S` instruction.
If, however, I run an individual command with sudo, `~` will be expanded to the desired homefolder.
So running `sudo rm -rf ~/testfoldercreatedfordeletion` in fact deletes the desired folder in my personal home directory. If I include the same line without `sudo` in the bash script, and run the bash script with `sudo` it does not.

Comment: The `/root/.emacs` implies the script is executed with the `root` user.

Comment: Do inside your script a `id -nu` before the `git` command, to see the effective user id.

Comment: @Jetchisel, I have, in fact, executed the bash script with sudo, since it contains a `pacman -S` instruction, which requires root privileges, if I am not mistaken and I read that it is not advised to include `sudo` in the bash script itself. 
Since this appears to be relevant information, I will add it to my initial post. 
Any suggestions on how to properly write the bash script so that it works on a fresh install, then?

Comment: A @user1934428: adding id -nu to the bash script before the git command has, unfortunately, not produced any extra output.

Comment: The standard utility `id` always prints **something**, either on stdout or stderr (try it on the command line, to make sure that you don't have a broken `id` installed on your system!). If you don't get any output, it could be that there is another executable of the same name in your PATH. You can find this by doing a `type -a id` in your script. In addition, I suggest that you invoke `id` with the absolute path.